# Route Ubuntu traffic to Windows XP VBox's VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, routing

I have the need to use SonicVPN Client to connect to my company's VPN. Unfortunately there are no ways to connect directly from Ubuntu. So I tried to set up a minimal Windows XP Virtual Machine in VirtualBox to run the SonicVPN Client on. All traffic that matches a specific network should be routed into that vbox. I have configured two network adapters. One Bridged and one Host-Only. The SonicVPN connection is shared over the Host-Only Adapter with "Windows internet sharing" (or so..).

Unfortunately I do not have a clue how to route the traffic correctly from Ubuntu.

I would be very happy, if someone had a tip for me.

Comment: Ubuntu's networking gui tool does have some features for VPN configuration. Have you toyed around with that a lot. Perhaps SonicWall uses typical VPN stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately this SonicWall does not use typical VPN stuff. That's why I have to go this way. Though you could configure it to be compatible with normal ipsec, my company configured it a way that makes me go mad. :)

Comment: There's always the "find another job" option. Actually, my solution to this kind of annoyance is to open a reverse ssh tunnel (from work) that I can connect to from where ever. Then through that I can coordinate getting access to other things. Hacky, but worky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the way to do it.
I'll describe my solution step by step.

1. Configure a Windows XP VBox with two Network Interfaces (one Bridged, one Host-Only)
2. Install the Sonicwall VPN Client software
3. Click on the newly created "SonicWALL VPN Connection" in your System configurations Network Connections Overview and choose Properties. On The 'Advanced' Tab enable 'Allow network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection' and use the Host-Only Adapter for 'Home network connection'
4. The TCP/IP settings for the host-only adapter should change to something like 192.168.0.1/255.255.55.0. If not, configure this manually.
5. In your Ubuntu system, configure the Host-Only vboxnet to use a static IP 192.168.0.2/255.255.255.0. The 192.168.0.1 should be "pingable" from within your Ubuntu host.
6. Now set up the routes: `sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev vboxnet7` (where vboxnet7 is my Host-Only Adapter)
7. Reconnect the SonicWALL VPN Client

Now you should be able to access the VPNs machines.